# как пользоваться mongoose-random

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Здравствуйте, я хочу получить случайные строки из mongodb при помощи плагина mongoose-random, но у меня не получается.

вот файлик index.js с подключением к базе.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useMongoClient: true});
module.exports = mongoose;
```

дальше идет так:

```
var mongoose = require('./'); // импорт верхнего кусочка кода
var random = require('mongoose-random');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    russian: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    english: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

schema.plugin(random());

module.exports = mongoose.model('Word', schema);
```

и тут вываливается ошибка:

```
C:\Users\ruslan\IdeaProjects\NodeNew\node_modules\mongoose-random\index.js:21
    schema.add(field);
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at random (C:\Users\ruslan\IdeaProjects\NodeNew\node_modules\mongoose-random\index.js:21:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ruslan\IdeaProjects\NodeNew\database\DbWords.js:24:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ruslan\IdeaProjects\NodeNew\routes\words.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\ruslan\IdeaProjects\NodeNew\routes\index.js:24:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ruslan\IdeaProjects\NodeNew\app.js:24:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Объясните кто сталкивался с этим, почему так?

Comment: мангуст надо зарекварийть нормально `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`. При создании схемы `new` забыл `var schema = new mongoose.Schema({` и `schema.plugin(random());` здесь вроде не нужны скобки после random т.е. так должно быть `schema.plugin(random);`

Comment: 1. mongoose нормально зареквайтил.
2. с new и без результат не меняется.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603254/mongoose-random-not-working тут пишут, что нужно именно random()